# Processing parenthesized expressions in Shunting Yard

Tags: c++, loops, code-readability, stl-algorithm, shunting-yard

I have the following hand-written loop to process parenthesized expressions:

```
while (!punctuators.empty() && punctuators.back().kind != '(')
{
    output.push_back(punctuators.back());
    punctuators.pop_back();
}
if (punctuators.empty())
    throw invalid_expression(") without matching matching (");
punctuators.pop_back();
```

(`output` and `punctuators` are both of type `std::vector<token>`, where `token` is a very simple `struct` that consists of a `char kind` and an `unsigned value` data member.)

I was wondering if switching from hand-written loops to algorithms would improve readability:

```
auto p = std::find_if(punctuators.rbegin(), punctuators.rend(),
                      [](token t){ return t.kind == '('; });
if (p == punctuators.rend())
    throw invalid_expression(") without matching matching (");
output.insert(output.end(), punctuators.rbegin(), p);
punctuators.erase(std::prev(p.base()), punctuators.end());
```

But somehow I feel that this code is a lot less readable, maybe due to the usage of reverse iterators, and especially the conversion to normal iterators. Is there a better solution? Would you agree that the hand-written loop is more readable, or am I simply not seeing the light yet when it comes to algorithms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need the right algorithm.

(untested code)

```
boost::algorithm::copy_while ( 
    punctuators.rbegin (), punctuators.rend (), 
    std::back_inserter ( output ),
    [](token t){ return t.kind != '('; });
```

If you're not using boost, you can write `copy_while` yourself fairly easily.

There's nothing magical about algorithms; you should get in the habit of writing your own.